# I have isset in my code, but it gives me error "Notice: Undefined index"

Tags: php

I have isset in my code, but it gives me error "Notice: Undefined index"

[this is the the screen with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHXKF.jpg)

**Index.php**

```
  <?php include ('\inc\functions.php'); 

        global $from, $to, $make, $model, $color, $type, $power, $reg_num;

    //if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    if(isset($_POST["search"])){
        $make = $_POST['brand'];
        $model = $_POST['model'];
        $reg_num = $_POST['reg_num'];
        $power = $_POST['horse_powers'];
        $color = $_POST['color'];
        $type = $_POST['type'];
        $from = $_POST['from'];
        $from = strtotime($from);
        $from = date("Y-m-d", $from);
        $to = $_POST['to'];
        $to = strtotime($to);
        $to = date("Y-m-d", $to);
    }

    //}
    /* else{
        $make = null;
        $model = null;
        $reg_num = null;
        $power = null;
        $color = null;
    } */

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Rent a car</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
            <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/date.js"></script>
              <script>
      $(function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
          dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
          showOn: "button",
          buttonImage: "images/date.gif",
          buttonImageOnly: false,
          buttonText: "Select date"
        });
      });
      </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <header>
                    <nav class="main_nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav><!-- End nav -->
                    <br class="clear" />
                    <aside class="search_class">
                        <h1>Search car</h1>
                        <p class="search_about">
                            <span class="about">About us</span>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                            ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
                            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.
                            <span><a href="about.html">more...</a></span>
                        </p>
                    </aside><!-- End Aside -->
                    <br class="clear" />
                </header><!-- End header -->
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <section>
                    <div class="results">
                        <div class="post_top">
                            <h2>Results</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post_middle">
                                    <?php                           
                                    switch ($type) {
                                        case "case1":
                                            echo '<table>';
                                            echo '<th>Make</th><th>Model</th><th>Color</th><th>Reg.Number</th><th>Power</th>';
                                            free_cars_period($from, $to, $servername, $username, $password, $db);
                                            //echo "Your favorite color is red! Case 1";
                                            echo '</table>';
                                            break;
                                        case "case2":
                                            echo '<table>';
                                            echo '<th>Make</th><th>Model</th><th>Color</th><th>Reg.Number</th><th>Power</th>';
                                            reserved_cars_period($from, $to, $servername, $username, $password, $db);
                                            //echo "Your favorite color is blue! Case 2";
                                            echo '</table>';
                                            break;
                                        case "case3":
                                            echo '<table>';
                                            echo '<th>Make</th><th>Model</th><th>Color</th><th>Reg.Number</th><th>Power</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th>';
                                            reserved_cars_criteria($from, $to, $servername, $username, $password, $db);
                                            //echo "Your favorite color is green! Case 3";
                                            echo '</table>';
                                            break;
                                        default:
                                            echo "Your favorite color is neither red, blue, nor green! Default Case";
                                    }
                                    ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post_bottom"></div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div><!-- End div "results" -->
                    <div class="form_wrapper">
                        <form action="index.php" method="POST">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="left">
                                    <label for="make">Make</label>
                                    <?php //Brand select                             

                                        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `brand` FROM `cars` ORDER BY `brand`";
                                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                                        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                                            //output data of each row
                                            echo "<select name='brand'>";
                                            //echo "<option value=>";
                                            echo "<option selected disabled>".'Choose brand'."</option>";
                                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                                echo "<option value='" . $row['brand'] . "'>" . $row['brand']."</option>";
                                            }
                                        }
                                         echo "</select>";  
                                    ?>
                                </li>
                                <li class="right">
                                    <label for="model">Model</label>
                                    <?php 

                                        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `model` FROM `cars` ORDER BY `model`";
                                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                                        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                                            //output data of each row
                                            echo "<select name='model'>";
                                            //echo "<option value=>";
                                            echo "<option selected disabled>".'Choose model'."</option>";
                                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                                echo "<option value='" . $row['model'] . "'>" . $row['model']."</option>";
                                            }
                                        }
                                         echo "</select>";                                   
                                    ?>
                                </li>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <li class="left">
                                    <label for="reg_num">Registration Number</label>
                                    <?php

                                        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `reg_num` FROM `cars` ORDER BY `reg_num`";
                                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                                        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                                            //output data of each row
                                            echo "<select name='reg_num'>";
                                            //echo "<option value=>";
                                            echo "<option selected disabled>".'Choose number'."</option>";
                                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                                echo "<option value='" . $row['reg_num'] . "'>" . $row['reg_num']."</option>";
                                            }
                                        }
                                         echo "</select>";
                                    ?>
                                </li>
                                <li class="right">
                                    <label for="power">Power</label>
                                    <?php

                                        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `horse_powers` FROM `cars` ORDER BY `horse_powers`";
                                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                                        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                                            //output data of each row
                                            echo "<select name='horse_powers'>";
                                            //echo "<option value=>";
                                            echo "<option selected disabled>".'Choose power'."</option>";
                                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                                echo "<option value='" . $row['horse_powers'] . "'>" . $row['horse_powers']."</option>";
                                            }
                                        }
                                         echo "</select>";
                                    ?>
                                </li>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <li class="left">
                                    <label for="color">Color</label>
                                    <?php 
                                        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `color` FROM `cars` ORDER BY `color`";
                                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                                        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                                            //output data of each row
                                            echo "<select name='color'>";
                                            //echo "<option value=>";
                                            echo "<option selected disabled>".'Choose color'."</option>";
                                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                                echo "<option value='" . $row['color'] . "'>" . $row['color']."</option>";
                                            }
                                        }
                                         echo "</select>";
                                    ?>
                                </li>
                                <li class="right">
                                    <label for="type">Type</label>
                                    <select name="type" id="type">
                                        <option selected disabled>Choose type</option>
                                        <option value="case1">Свободни коли за период</option>
                                        <option value="case2">Заети коли за период</option>
                                        <option value="case3">Заети коли по критерии</option>
                                    </select>                               
                                </li>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <li class="left">
                                    <label for="from">From</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="from" id="from" class="datepicker" />
                                </li>
                                <li class="right">
                                    <label for="to">To</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="to" id="to" class="datepicker" />                              
                                </li>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <li class="right">
                                    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" id="submit" />
                                </li>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </ul>
                        </form>
                    </div><!-- End div "form_wrapper" -->
                </section><!-- End section -->
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <footer class="footer">
                    <p>All right reserved solutions.</p>
                </footer><!-- End footer -->
            </div><!-- End container -->
        </body>
    </html>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
    global $servername, $username, $password, $db;
//  global $from, $to, $make, $model, $color, $type, $power, $reg_num;

    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $db="naemkola";

    global $servername, $username, $password, $db;

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }



function connect($servername, $username, $password, $db){
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $db="naemkola";


    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);
    return $conn;
} 

global $conn;
$conn = connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

function select_all_cars(/*mysqli $conn */){
//  $conn = connect();
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $db="naemkola";

    $conn = connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cars`";

    $result_qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_qr)){
//      echo '<tr><td>'.$row['brand'].'</td><td>'.$row['model'].'</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['brand'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['model'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['color'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['reg_num'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['horse_powers'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

    }
    return $result_qr;  
}

function free_cars_period($from, $to, $servername, $username, $password, $db){

    $conn = connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

    $sql2 = "SELECT `brand`, `model`, `reg_num`, `horse_powers`, `color`
            FROM ((`clients_cars` INNER JOIN `cars` ON `clients_cars`.`cars_id` = `cars`.`id`)
            LEFT JOIN `clients` ON `clients_cars`.`clients_id` = `clients`.`id`)
            WHERE (`rent_date` >= '$from' AND `return_date` <= '$to') AND `clients_id` IS NULL";


    $result_qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2); 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_qr)){

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['brand'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['model'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['color'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['reg_num'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['horse_powers'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    return $result_qr;      
}


function reserved_cars_period($from, $to, $servername, $username, $password, $db){

    $conn = connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

    $sql2 = "SELECT `brand`, `model`, `reg_num`, `horse_powers`, `color`
            FROM ((`clients_cars` INNER JOIN `cars` ON `clients_cars`.`cars_id` = `cars`.`id`)
            LEFT JOIN `clients` ON `clients_cars`.`clients_id` = `clients`.`id`)
            WHERE (`rent_date` >= '$from' AND `return_date` <= '$to') AND `clients_id` IS NOT NULL";

    $result_qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2); 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_qr)){

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['brand'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['model'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['color'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['reg_num'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['horse_powers'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    return $result_qr;      
}

function reserved_cars_criteria($from, $to, $servername, $username, $password, $db){

    $conn = connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

    $sql2 = "SELECT `brand`, `model`, `reg_num`, `horse_powers`, `color`, `first_name`, `last_name`
            FROM ((`clients_cars` INNER JOIN `cars` ON `clients_cars`.`cars_id` = `cars`.`id`)
            LEFT JOIN `clients` ON `clients_cars`.`clients_id` = `clients`.`id`)
            WHERE (`rent_date` >= '$from' AND `return_date` <= '$to') AND `clients_id` IS NOT NULL";


    $result_qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2); 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_qr)){

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['brand'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['model'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['color'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['reg_num'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['horse_powers'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['first_name'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['last_name'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    return $result_qr;      
}

?>
```

**The error lines:**

```
Notice: Undefined index: brand in C:\Xampp\htdocs\homework\final_task\index.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: model in C:\Xampp\htdocs\homework\final_task\index.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: reg_num in C:\Xampp\htdocs\homework\final_task\index.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: horse_powers in C:\Xampp\htdocs\homework\final_task\index.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: color in C:\Xampp\htdocs\homework\final_task\index.php on line 11
```

Before submitting form i`m checking if the search is isset and if isset it have to submit and assign variables, but it gives me error.
How can i fix this error ? thanks in advance

Comment: You are *not* using `isset()` on those lines.

Comment: what's inside $_POST ?

Comment: Thanks  @JohnConde it fixed my problem.